# Downloading a JNLP File in Java

Tags: java, download, jnlp

I want to download a JNLP file from a given link. I already know how to go through the authentication process. How can I download that file? Eventually I want to create the following method.

```
downloadJNLP(String url, String path){
   ...
}
```

Comment: By 'download a JNLP file' do you actually mean 'launch the application'?  In your method signature, what does 'path' mean?

Answer (score 1):

Just like you would download any file: [reading URL in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)